# Button not clickable in "Hello World" Cordova application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I Created a new Cordova application and ran the `cordova run ios` command to get the default cordova blink screen.

When I add a button it is not clickable. I have written the action in pure vanila JS. I initially tried wring the button action in a separate file and importing that as a script file but that too didn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">            
        //Create a new To-Do
        function createNewToDo()
        {
            alert('hi');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>   

  /******** Both buttons not clickable     
            <button class="button" id="getDate">Get Date</button>
            <button type="button" class="addToDo" onclick="createNewToDo()">/>TO DO</button>            
  *********/
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag, it doesn't allow onclick.

Just edit it to allow onclick by adding 'unsafe-inline' to default-src section or to script-src. Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
```

BTW, if you enable remote debugging for your device and open desktop Safari to inspect the app, you will get an error message like this:

> Refused to execute a script for an inline event handler because
>   'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the script-src directive nor the
>   default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

Comment: +1 for the debugging tip. I have been testing on the simulator all this while. Will report back with my findings.

Comment: Devices should appear on Safari desktop on Debug tab (I think you have to enable the developer mode on Safari, or use Safari Technology Preview which has it enabled by default)

Comment: I already had "unsafe-inline", it did not make any difference.

Comment: @BK in your example you have the `'unsafe-inline'` only for `style-src`, not for `default-src`

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">            
        //Create a new To-Do
        function createNewToDo()
        {
            alert('hi');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>   

       <!--- Both buttons not clickable   --->
            <button class="button" id="getDate">Get Date</button>
            <button type="button" class="addToDo" onclick="createNewToDo()">TO DO</button>            

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```